# Calling alexa's timer api with python not working

Tags: python, api, alexa-skills-kit

I tried the following code to call alexa's timer via api:

```
timer = {
    "duration": "PT15S",
    "timerLabel": "Change name",
    "creationBehavior": {
        "displayExperience": {
            "visibility": "VISIBLE"
        }
    },
    "triggeringBehavior": {
        "operation": {
            "type": "ANNOUNCE", 
            "textToAnnounce": [
                {
                    "locale": "en-US",
                    "text": "Break time"
                }
            ]
        },
        "notificationConfig": {
            "playAudible": True 
        }
    }
}


class TimerHandler(AbstractRequestHandler):
    def can_handle(self, handler_input):
        return ask_utils.is_intent_name("TimerHandler")(handler_input)

    def handle(self, handler_input):
        request_envelope = handler_input.request_envelope
        permissions = request_envelope.context.system.user
       
        if not (permissions):        
            return (
                    handler_input.response_builder
                    .add_directive({
                        type: "Connections.SendRequest",
                        name: "AskFor",
                        payload: {
                        "@type": "AskForPermissionsConsentRequest",
                        "@version": "1",
                        "permissionScope": "alexa::alerts:timers:skill:readwrite"
                        },
                        token: "<string>"
                        })
                    .speak("This skill needs permission to access your timer")
                    .ask()
                    .response
                    )
        else:
            return requests.post("https://api.amazonalexa.com/v1/alerts/timers", timer),
```

requests.status_code

However, I received the following error.

```
 Error received:
    [ERROR] AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'deserialized_types'
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/var/task/ask_sdk_core/skill_builder.py", line 112, in wrapper
        return skill.serializer.serialize(response_envelope)  # type:ignore
      File "/var/task/ask_sdk_core/serialize.py", line 125, in serialize
        return {key: self.serialize(val) for key, val in iteritems(obj_dict)}
      File "/var/task/ask_sdk_core/serialize.py", line 125, in <dictcomp>
        return {key: self.serialize(val) for key, val in iteritems(obj_dict)}
      File "/var/task/ask_sdk_core/serialize.py", line 114, in serialize
        k: k for k in obj.deserialized_types.keys()
```

Could someone please please please help me out :( It would really mean the world to me as I can't figure out what's the problem nor can figure out what's the error for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `handle` method returns wrong type of result.

It must return instance of `ask_sdk_model.response.Response` type and it does it properly if condition `if not permissions` is True. But if it's False it returns `requests.models.Response` instance. Though these classes have the same name they are from different frameworks and are not compatible.

Perhaps you need to process the response of this POST request and then return the desired result as the `ask_sdk_model.response.Response` instance like this:

```
return handler_input.response_builder.response
```

Comment: Hi @SergeyShubin Thank you soo much for helping me out! You literally made my day, as I pretty much lost hope. Now that's finalized. I am trying to request the apiaccess token of the user. Do you know if I should that within the same function? if so, where and how?

Comment: @Daniyaldehleh I'm afraid I will not be very helpful here. I did not used this framework and this answer was mostly based on my experience with `requests` library. There is a [documentation entry](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/smapi/alexa-settings-api-reference.html#get-the-api-access-token-and-device-id) about getting API access token but I found no examples of using it in the [sample applications](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/alexa-skills-kit-sdk-for-python/sample-skills.html). You can always make a new question though :)

Comment: God bless you! You've helped me a lot already and I am thankful to have you in the community :)